# Calling action method in MVC with $.post and then returning an object for Edit not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to call an action method in an MVC4 application using jQuery. I'm using a button on Edit form shown in fancybox:

```
<input type="button" value="Approve" id="Approve" />
```

I'm using a jquery `$.post` on this button click

```
$("#Approve").click(function () {
    debugger;
    var ID = $("#AjaxGrid tbody tr:first").attr("data-pkey");
    debugger;
    var postParams = { Id: ID }
    $.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Approve"))', postParams)
        .fail(function () {
            alert("error occured while Approving");
        }); 
});
```

In the controller the following is my action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Approve(long id)
{
    Evaluation evaluation = db.EvaluationRepository.GetByID(id);
    evaluation.EvaluationStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(EvaluationStatusType.Approved);
    return PartialView(evaluation);
}
```

But I always get the same result i.e. `error occured while Approving`

Can any one help me in finding what's wrong?

**got this error with F12 on browser**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

---

**and this annoying detail**

Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Approve(Int64)' in 'CubicHRMWeb.Areas.Employees.Controllers.EvaluationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Approve(Int64)' in 'CubicHRMWeb.Areas.Employees.Controllers.EvaluationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Approve(Int64)' in 'CubicHRMWeb.Areas.Employees.Controllers.EvaluationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +654635
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0(ParameterInfo parameterInfo) +18
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +133
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +237
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862381
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

Comment: In the console (hit F12 in your browser) there will be a more descriptive error from the HTTP request, can you please post what that is.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: In that case there is an error in your Action. Put a breakpoint on the `Evaluation evaluation = db....` line and step through it to find out what the error is. My guess would be that the passed `id` isn't found and that `evaluation` is null.

Comment: Can you clarify: **1** do you have antiforgerytoken protection on server side?, **2** Can you show your route config?

Comment: From your stack trace it appears the `id` parameter of your AJAX call is null, `data-pkey` is empty for the selected element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Approve" id="Approve" data-action="@Url.Action("Approve")" />
```

JS:

```
Number.tryParseInt = function(value) {
    return value.toString().match(/^(\d)/) != null;
}

Number.tryParseFloat = function(value) {
    return value.toString().match(/^(\d|\d\.|\.\d)/) != null;
}


$("#Approve").click(function () {

    var 
        id = $("#AjaxGrid tbody tr:first").data('pkey'),
        postParams = { id: 0 };

    if (!Number.tryParseFloat(id)) { 
        alert('id "' + id + '" is not a number');
        return false;
    }

    postParams.id = parseInt(id);

    $.post($(this).data('action'), postParams)
        .done(function(data) {
            alert('ok Approving: ' + data.EvaluationStatusID);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('error occured while Approving');
        }); 

    return false;
});
```

C#:

Why you are using ActionResult if not using the return?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Approve(long id)
{
    Evaluation evaluation = db.EvaluationRepository.GetByID(id);
    evaluation.EvaluationStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(EvaluationStatusType.Approved);

    return Json(evaluation);
}
```

Need you a larger number of '2.147.483.647'?, if you continue with the error, try using int:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Approve(int id)
{
    Evaluation evaluation = db.EvaluationRepository.GetByID(id);
    evaluation.EvaluationStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(EvaluationStatusType.Approved);

    return Json(evaluation);
}
```

Comment: 1 - What is the value of "postParams.id"​​? 2 - Have you another method with the same name but with different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace it appears the `id` parameter of your AJAX call is null, `data-pkey` is empty for the selected element.

Without seeing your HTML I can't tell you why this is but you need to look at and change the `$("#AjaxGrid tbody tr:first")` selector.

Comment: thats most annoying Rory, when i debuged through jquery and action, ID value was there

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a Circular Refrence Issue

My Model Class

```
 public class Evaluation
{ 
   [Key]
   public int ID {get; set;} 
   public int UserID {get; set;} //whose evaluation is due 
   public DateTime EvaluationDueOn {get; set;} 
   public DateTime EvaluatedOn {get; set;}
   public decimal evaluationAmount {get; set;} 
   public string  comments {get; set;}
   public string  ApproverID {get; set;} //(userid of staff doing approval) 
   public int EvaluationStatusID { get; set; }


   public virtual Users EvaluatedUser { get; set; }

   public virtual Users ApprovingUser { get; set; }
}
```

uses Navigational properties like

```
public virtual Users EvaluatedUser { get; set; 

public virtual Users ApprovingUser { get; set; }
```

and Serialization problem occurs due to this Circular Refrence